# Is curvature of space actually free, i.e. not determined by the matter distribution?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

Actually Einstein's field equations only seem to make a statement on the Ricci's tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$  which is determined by the matter distribution given by the stress tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$.

That means, in the general case the EFE's do not tell us about the curvature, i.e. Riemann's curvature tensor. It seems that in particular cases, like spaces of constant curvature or given perfect spherical symmetry as in the Schwarzschild case the curvature is nevertheless known.

But imagine a binary double star system. There is no apparent (easy) symmetry.

The question is: Is Riemann's curvature tensor determined for such a system ? Or is Weyl's tensor which is simply said just the difference between curvature tensor and the Ricci tensor (being zero outside of the stars) in such a case completely free ?

On the other hand, if a solution, i.e. the metric, of the EFE's is known, Riemann's curvature tensor can simply calculated without direct use of the EFE's in the calculation. I guess, for a binary double star system this is at least numerically possible.

So the question is: in a general case is Riemann's curvature tensor determined ? And if not, what does it mean if it is not determined, i.e. free ?

Comment: While it is true that the LHS of the EFE involve only $R_{\mu\nu}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$ it should be noted that the EFE are themselves an equation for $g_{\mu\nu}$. Once the equations are solved, the solution is a particular $g_{\mu\nu}$ from which you can compute the Riemann tensor with the usual formula. As such, the EFE *do determine* the Riemann tensor as well.

Answer (score 2):

To solve a differential equation, you will also need initial or boundary conditions. In the case of your binary star system, for example, this will come because you will need to patch the exterior and interior solutions of the stars together using the junction conditions. This is similar to when you solve Electrodynamics problems and need to "glue" two solutions across a surface.

Do notice that Electrodynamics also does not give equations for each specific derivative of the electromagnetic fields. Instead, it gives only the combinations that fix the divergence and the curl. Nevertheless, when aligned to the initial or boundary conditions, this is enough to completely determine the field. This is similar in General Relativity. The left-hand side of the EFE only involves the Ricci tensor, but when you add in your initial or boundary conditions for the metric you can solve the problem uniquely.

If you are interested, you might want to check about the [initial value formulation of General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_formulation_(general_relativity)).

Comment: I'm not sure I totally agree about the comments regarding initial conditions? We don't really need to fix all the free functions in the metric to determine the Riemann tensor (the components are simply functions of the metric components, the same as the Ricci tensor). I also disagree that the EFE only gives the Ricci tensor. We solve for the metric, and we have exactly as much knowledge about the Ricci tensor as we do about the Riemann tensor. Initial/boundary conditions fix the free functions in the *metric* and is not related to this Ricci tensor vs Riemann tensor thing.

Comment: I see your points. Let's assume we have no matter at all. Should we then conclude that the Riemann tensor is zero ? Or is a for instance a constant non-zero curvature possible even without matter ?

Comment: @FredericThomas if we assume we have no matter at all then we assume $g_{00}=0$ everywhere, i.e. there is no spacetime. Einstein field equations (EFE) are second order differential equations for metric. Mathematically, a differential equation has infinitely many solution. Physically however, there is only one solution which is determined by the physical boundary condition. In case of EFE that are the values of  stress-energy tensor on the boundary.

Comment: @Eletie Once we *solve* the EFE they do give the Riemann tensor just as much as they give the Ricci tensor. What I meant is that the EFE determine only the Ricci tensor algebraically (as in: LHS = RHS). Once you solve the differential equations they do give the Riemann tensor and everything else. I find it possible the Riemann tensor does not depend on every single detail of the metric (in which case the initial conditions might be sufficient but not necessary), but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Nevertheless, do notice that both Schwarzschild spacetime, Minkowski spacetime and GW solutions are all vacuum solutions of the EFE. They only differ in initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: @FredericThomas Non-zero curvature is possible even without matter. Some examples are gravitational waves and black holes, which are vacuum solutions (the stress tensor vanishes identically everywhere in spacetime (the singularity is not part of spacetime)). These solutions are Ricci-flat (the Ricci tensor vanishes), but the Riemann tensor is still non-zero.

Comment: @NickolasAlves okay yes I agree with you there, and we probably do agree on this overall! Perhaps it's a matter of interpretation, but I'd answer the original question of whether spacetime curvature is determined by the matter distribution as: yes! dynamically through the EFE PDE's.

Comment: @Eletie I only agree partially. While the EFEs play a significant role, the matter distribution alone is not sufficient to determine the gravitational field as a role because the gravitational field also has its own independent degrees of freedom. A nice example is the existence of GWs on vacuum. The EFEs state how spacetime and matter *interact*, rather than how matter determines spacetime curvature.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I don't disagree, my point is that the EFE determine no more or no less about the Ricci tensor than they do about the Riemann curvature tensor. I think the OP seems think the EFE fix the Ricci scalar but leave freedom in the Riemann tensor, but in actuality we should only really talk about the freedom in the metric tensor. Whether we need additional constraints (or symmetries) to find the metric components doesn't change this fact.

Comment: @Eletie But the EFE do fix the Ricci tensor, even before we actually solve them for the metric. The EFE alone are able to fix the Ricci tensor, but not the Riemann tensor. If you tell me the spacetime is in vacuum, I can already tell you the Ricci tensor vanishes, but I can't say anything about the (rest of the) Riemann tensor

Comment: @NíckolasAlves The vacuum is a special case, but in general the Ricci tensor components will be functions of the metric that need additional constraints to fix them completely. Interpreting the EFE as algebraic equations for the Ricci scalar alone feels very odd, when clearly it comes from a theory of matter $T_{\mu \nu}$ and the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: @Eletie Fair enough. I agree with you. Perhaps the new version of the answer is better formulated.

Answer (score 1):

The Einstein field equations $G_{\mu \nu} = \kappa T_{\mu \nu}$ are differential equations for the metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$, which itself completely determines the (Levi-Civita) Riemann curvature tensor $R^{\lambda}{}_{\mu \nu \rho}$.

This is the way you should think about the field equations:

- assign some matter distribution for $T_{\mu \nu}$ (depending on the problem at hand)
- solve the EFE for the metric tensor (which of course is usually also aided by symmetry considerations and assumptions)

From here, i.e., your metric solution, you can extract all geometric information you need including all the curvature tensors you mentioned.